# Django - Customize error email sent to admins using mail_admins in logging. Too much sensetive information

Tags: python, django, logging

The current email that goes out to admins during errors contains sensitive information so I'd like to change course and instead include instructions on how to quickly view the log files and find the traceback. I'm not sure how to piggyback off the current functionality and add a custom message rather than the standard message. So any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own handler for this.

Normally you would set it up as

```
"class": "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler",
```

Instead create your own class, inherit from AdminEmailHandler and overwrite the method

Quick, dirty, not tested:

```
from django.utils.log import AdminEmailHandler
class MyAdminEmailHandler(AdminEmailHandler):

    def send_mail(self, subject, message, *args, **kwargs):
        # Handle you sending an email
```

Now the class would

```
"class": "myapp.utils.log.MyAdminEmailHandler",
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this a lot. Is there a best place to define my new class?

Comment: I tend to follow Django's structure for most things, so myapp/utils/log.py sounds like a logic place. You might already have a  myapp/utils.py so you have to choose a different place.